# Update by query (async / task) - No failure info - Handling Conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running an update by query as a task (wait_for_completion=false), with 'conflicts=proceed'. I do expect version conflicts to happen sometimes and can see that info in get task response (/task/task-id). I plan to reprocess the conflicted records.

Problem: When version conflicts do happen, **I don't see the conflicted record ids under 'failures' array** for me to be able to reprocess. Any suggestions in this regard are greatly appreciated.

```
"response" : {
    "took" : 69055,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "total" : 286164,
    "updated" : 285885,
    "created" : 0,
    "deleted" : 0,
    "batches" : 287,
    "version_conflicts" : 279,
    "noops" : 0,
    "retries" : {
      "bulk" : 0,
      "search" : 0
    },
    "throttled" : "0s",
    "throttled_millis" : 0,
    "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
    "throttled_until" : "0s",
    "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
    "failures" : [ ]
  }
```

Note: Another observation is that if we run this with 'conflicts=abort', then we see failure info in the response as expected.

Below is the update by query template being used,

```html
{
    "conflicts": "proceed",
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "location_id": {
                "value": 121
            }
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "params": {},
        "source": "ctx._source.sys_updated_at = new Date();ctx._source.location_name = 'New York';"
    }
}
```

Comment: With conflicts=abort you only see the first conflict not the other ones since the process is aborted on the first conflict. Depending on the query you're doing (i.e. a query that selects documents to be modified based on the value of a field), re-running the query should only resurface the documents that still have the old value (those are the ones that were in conflict).

Comment: Thanks @Val, what you have mentioned aligns with my understanding in case of 'conflicts=abort'. In case of 'conflicts=proceed' I was wondering if you have any thoughts on collecting the details of records that conflicted. This will allow me to handle such records.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the query that you're using to update your records? or is it a `match_all`?

Comment: It is a term query, I have added a sample template.

Comment: Ok, in this case what you can do is to modify your query to add a constraint that checks whether `location_name` is not `New York`, because the documents that conflicted didn't have this field updated. So on the next run, only those that conflicted would be updated, and you can re-run a few times until you get no conflicts.

Comment: It would be more interesting, though, to know WHY there are conflicts and maybe prevent that condition from happening.

Comment: Excellent, that will work. My only complication is that there can be many such fields (dynamically). I guess it can also be handled and hence not a huge problem. Wish the conflicted record ids was readily available from task API response. Thanks so much, I could mark your response as an answer, but it is under comments.

Comment: The reason there could be conflicts is because, the update can potentially touch thousands of records. which means the update could run for couple of minutes. It is possible that during that time, one of the records could have been modified by application code.

Comment: Makes sense! Anyway, I've cerated an answer, as that could be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to modify your query to add a constraint that checks whether `location_name` is not `New York`, because the documents that conflicted didn't have this field updated.

So on the next run, only those that conflicted would be updated, and you can re-run a few times until you get no conflicts.

This is how the query should look like this (maybe your field is called `location_name.keyword` instead):

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "location_id": {
              "value": 121
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "location_name": "New York"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "params": {},
    "source": "ctx._source.sys_updated_at = new Date();ctx._source.location_name = 'New York';"
  }
}
```